# Is there a Python argument similar to R's matrix(c())?

Tags: python, r, matrix, vector

I am looking at a code in R which I found online. Here is the link: http://epirecip.es/epicookbook/chapters/kr08/3_4/r_desolve

I had a question about this line in particular.

```
beta <- matrix(c(2.089, 2.089, 2.086, 2.037, 2.089, 9.336, 2.086, 2.037, 2.086, 2.086, 
                 2.086, 2.037, 2.037, 2.037, 2.037, 2.037), nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

I know that in R, the c() function returns a vector and matrix() creates a matrix from the given set of values. In that regard, does python have a similar argument/command like the `matrix(c())` argument? Which could do the same thing? If so, any answers, tips or useful links are welcome.

Comment: You probably want to use `numpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this produce the output you want?

```
import numpy as np


# Set of values in the form of a numpy array.
l = np.arrange(16)

# If it's not already a numpy array use this
matrix = np.asarray(l).reshape(4, 4)

# But in this case you can just do
matrix = np.reshape(4, 4)

print(matrix)
```

Comment: `[x for x in range(16)]` is an unnecessarily complicated way of writing `list(range(16))` but that is unnecessary, you can just do `np.array(range(16))` but *even that* is unnecessary, you can just do `np.arange(16)`

Comment: Well don't I feel silly now! Ahaha, thank you! I appreciate the information!

Comment: @BeanBagTheCat  thank you both for your insight